# How to Convert Dimensions.get("window").height to percentage?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

I Got this small issue of converting the value of Dimensions.get("window").height to percentage and I need to minus the value to another percentage value ... I am Extremely Sorry If Its A Bad Question I am New To React Native ( learning Views )

Orginal -  height:Dimensions.get("window").height - 200

I Need Something Like -- height:Dimensions.get("window").height - "10%"

overlayStyle={{

```
                height:Dimensions.get("window").height-200, // I want to convert It to Percentage 
                width:Dimensions.get("window").width-50,
                borderRadius:20,
                alignItems:"center",
                paddingTop:"15%",

                }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we can use

```
const height = Dimensions.get("window").height;

const newHeight = height - 0.1*height;
```

Comment: Ya Thanks It Worked.

Comment: I Made That To Something Like This                    `height:Dimensions.get("window").height-(0.3*Dimensions.get("window").height)`                 And It worked